# Как подключиться непосредственно к PDB через Bequeath соединение?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle18c, oracle19c

До введения подключаемых БД (*pluggable database=PDB*) можно было установить *Bequeath* соединение, установив переменную окружения `ORACLE_SID=orcl` и подключаться указывая только пользователя и пароль в строке соединения.

Например:

```
export ORACLE_SID=orcl; . oraenv
sqlplus -l me/me
```

При этом, процессы с установленным *Bequeath* соединением выглядели так:

```
SQL> host ps -ef|grep 32464
oracle   32464 32463  0 16:44 pts/1    00:00:00 <path>/oracle/product/11.2.0/home/bin/sqlplus
oracle   32465 32464  0 16:44 ?        00:00:00 oracleorcl (DESCRIPTION=(LOCAL=YES)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=beq)))
```

Сервер процесс запущен самим клиентом (в д.сл. SQL*Plus), то есть без участия прослушивателя. Обмен данными между ними по *Bequeath* протоколу боле эффективен по сравнению с TCP сокетами.

Для соединения с подключаемыми БД необходимо в строке соединения указывать имя сервиса: `me/me@server/service`, то есть задействовать прослушиватель.

Есть ли возможность в новых версиях установить *Bequeath* соединение к PDB?

Answer (score 2):

Такая возможность появилась в версии 18c. В дополнение к `ORACLE_SID` можно установить новую переменную окружения `ORACLE_PDB_SID` (пока не документирована):

```
$ export ORACLE_PDB_SID=pdb1
$ sqlplus / as sysdba

Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.3.0.0.0

SQL> show con_name

CON_NAME
------------------------------
PDB1

SQL> host ps -ef|grep 3975
oracle    3975  3974  0 21:25 pts/1    00:00:00 <path>/19.3.0/home/bin/sqlplus  as sysdba
oracle    3976  3975  0 21:25 ?        00:00:00 oracleorcl (DESCRIPTION=(LOCAL=YES)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=beq)))
```

Но это работает только для привилегированных пользователей:

```
$ sqlplus me/me

ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```